# angular unit test $httpBackend got Unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-mock

Here is my code:

```
export class httpService {

constructor($q, $http){
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$http = $http;
}

static getError(response) {
    if (response.data && response.data.messages) {
        return response.data.messages;
    } else {
        return ["Sorry, there is an internal issue..."];
    }
}

httpRequest(url, method, data) {
    url = encodeURI(url);
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }, function (response) {
        deferred.reject(httpService.getError(response));
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

}

My test code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngMock from 'angular-mocks';
import {httpService as HttpService} from '../http.service';

describe("httpService", ()=>{
    var httpService;
    var $q;
    var $timeout;
    var $httpBackend;
    var campaignHttpRequestHandler;
    var campaignTestUrl = 'api/campaign/aGJhZ2ZmZ2RmcmZ0';
    var campaignData = {
        "articles": [
            {
                "id": "1207",
                "type": "a",
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "940",
                "type": "p",
                "order": 2
            },
            {
                "id": "1268",
                "type": "a",
                "order": 3
            },
            {
                "id": "954",
                "type": "p",
                "order": 4
            }
        ],
        "year_month": "201606",
    };

    beforeEach(inject((_$q_, _$timeout_, _$httpBackend_)=>{
        $q = _$q_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        campaignHttpRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('Get', campaignTestUrl).respond(campaignData);

    }));

    beforeEach(()=>{
        httpService = new HttpService($q, $httpBackend);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe("#httpRequest()", ()=>{

        it('should get campaign data', ()=>{
            $httpBackend.expect('Get', campaignTestUrl);

            httpService.httpRequest(campaignTestUrl, 'Get').then(
                (response)=>{
                    expect(response).toEqual(campaignData);
                }
            );

            $httpBackend.flush();


        });


    });





});
```

The Error:

```
#httpRequest()
      ✖ should get campaign data
        Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.5)
      Error: Unexpected request: [object Object] undefined
```

And I debuged into the source code, $http has been replaced with $httpBackend. 
Somehow, the first parameter of $httpBackend: method, it is an object contains method, url, data, the same request parameter as in $http. Apparently, it is wrong. But I don't know how to fix it~

Help please. 
I have been stuck here for whole day~

Comment: What happens when you use 'GET' and not 'Get', as documented? Or even better: whenGET() and expectGET()?

Comment: @JBNizet the same error, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: $http isn't equal to $httpBackend, they can't be used interchangeably. This kind of mistake isn't going to happen if services are tested the suggested way. Is there a reason why `HttpService` class is instantiated manually?

Comment: $httpBackend is the mock up for $http. I want to test this service, so I need to use $httpBackend to mock $http. @estus

Comment: [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpBackend) is the *backend* for `$http`. `$http` [depends on it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#dependencies). You can't pass it instead of `$http`. You've already got the correct answer, btw.

Comment: @estus , yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass $http instead of $httpBackend as the constructor parameter.

Create a variable of type $http inside your test code and pass it like this

```
beforeEach(()=>{
     httpService = new HttpService($q, $http)
});
```

It will surely work.

Comment: ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Comment: beforeEach(()=>{
        httpService = new HttpService($q, $http);
    });

Comment: you need to define $http, like you have define $httpBackend before using it in your test code...

Comment: Tried to inject $http, but got Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress.

Comment: I don't understand why inject $http instead of $httpBackend, $httpBackend mocks up the $http.

Comment: Finally, problem solved! My problem was more than that! Yes, should inject $http instead of $httpbackend. AND, beaware of the case. It should be UPPERCASE! UPPERCASE for GET!!!